# jenkins shall fail on errors during rpm install job

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins

I have an deployment task that is executed on my test machine. The purpose is to test the freshly build rpm from jenkins on the very same machine.

Therefore I set up a deploy job in jenkins that executes the following shell lines:

```
artifact=$(ls build/*.rpm | head -1)
sudo /usr/local/sbin/jenkins-rpm-install $artifact
rm -rf build/
```

To install the rpm I made a small shell script that jenkins has exclusive sudo permissions for.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# allows jenkins to install rpm as privileged user
#
# add the following line to /etc/sudoers:
# jenkins    ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/jenkins-rpm-install
#

artifact=$1

rpm -vv --install --force $artifact
```

Now I have the problem: Whenever the rpm install fails jenkins does not recognize the error code and marks the build as success.

Does anyone have an idea how to properly solve this? 
Also tips to improve this process are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simply checking for rpm error's code in your script and report it to Jenkins yourself?

```
rpm -vv --install --force $artifact
error_code=$?
if [[ err_code > 0 ]]; then exit $?; fi
```

Or with overload:

```
rpm -vv --install --force $artifact || exit $?
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work as expected...

`warning: %post(test-1-1.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 1`
`# echo $?`
`0`

Comment: It appears the last error code is not properly set after an error. Well, in that case you can scan the console message and if you find any mentions of error, `exit 1` yourself.

Comment: looks like a rpm problem... I guess thats a different question I have to ask. Or do you mean with "scan" something that jenkins should do?

Comment: Nah, you're right, it appears to be an rpm problem now, not jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

If within configuration you are using `execute shell` step Jenkins will mark build as failed if `exit code`!= `0`.

If might be sufficient to alter your script by adding `exit $?` at the end.