# rpm scriptlet error does not send proper exit code during install

Tags: jenkins, rpm, rpmbuild

I let jenkins build rpm with post-install scriptlets that perform several tasks during install.
One of those may fail and send an error like

```
warning: %post(test-1-1.noarch) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
```

Unfortunately this seems not to result in a proper exit status from the rpm call.

```
# echo $? 
0
```

Actually I need the rpm install send an exit state >0

Is there some hidden rpm option that I am missing or is there something missing in my scriptlet?

This is how my scriptlets look like (created by effing package manager via jenkins with variables <%= installPath %>, <%= webUser %> inserted during creation)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

INSTALLPATH=<%= installPath %>
WEBUSER=<%= webUser %>
HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`

mkdir -p $INSTALLPATH/app/cache
setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:"$WEBUSER":rwX $INSTALLPATH/app/cache
setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:"$WEBUSER":rwX $INSTALLPATH/app/cache

mkdir -p $INSTALLPATH/app/logs
setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:"$WEBUSER":rwX $INSTALLPATH/app/logs
setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:"$WEBUSER":rwX $INSTALLPATH/app/logs

mkdir -p $INSTALLPATH/web/cache
setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:"$WEBUSER":rwX $INSTALLPATH/web/cache
setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:"$WEBUSER":rwX $INSTALLPATH/web/cache

sudo su $WEBUSER -c "php $INSTALLPATH/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php"
sudo su $WEBUSER -c "php $INSTALLPATH/app/console cache:warmup"

sudo su $WEBUSER -c "php $INSTALLPATH/app/console assets:install $INSTALLPATH/web"

sudo su $WEBUSER -c "php $INSTALLPATH/app/console doctrine:database:drop --if-exists --no-interaction --force"
sudo su $WEBUSER -c "php $INSTALLPATH/app/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists"
sudo su $WEBUSER -c "php $INSTALLPATH/app/console doctrine:schema:create"
```

The rpm install is called by

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# allows jenkins to install rpm as privileged user
#
# add the following line to /etc/sudoers:
# jenkins    ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/jenkins-rpm-install
#

artifact=$1

rpm -vv --install --force $artifact
err_code=$?

if [[ err_code > 0 ]]; then exit 1; fi
```

Any recommendations are welcome.

(This question is a follow up from [jenkins shall fail on errors during rpm install job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188501/jenkins-shall-fail-on-errors-during-rpm-install-job/37192758?noredirect=1#comment61947514_37192758))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rpm (from @rpm.org, not from @rpm5.org) chose to treat errors from %post as non-fatal (i.e. the exit code is zero) quite some years ago. There are no re-enabler options I am aware of. Well you can detect the warning: message instead of checking the exit code.

Comment: looks like this plugin is doing the job: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin